# OCR using openCV

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opencv

I wants to give effects on image using openCV, I am struggling from last 2 days and do little bit from my side. But not get the good output. Till now I only convert into gray. how to achieve remaining effects?

I use this method for convert in Gray

```
- (void)blackAndWhite {


cv::Mat  dst;

cv::Mat src=[self cvMatFromUIImage:iv.image];


if( !src.data )
{ std::cout<<"Usage: ./Histogram_Demo <path_to_image>"<<std::endl;
}

/// Convert to grayscale
cvtColor( src, src, CV_BGR2GRAY );

/// Apply Histogram Equalization
//equalizeHist( src, dst );

iv.image =[self UIImageFromCVMat:src];   



}
```

Thanks

1)  After convert in GRAY
[image]

2) Apply Black and White effect

[image]

3) Remove dark black background and change image orientation.

[image]

Comment: what do want to achieve actually?

Comment: I wants read characters from image, I already implement code for that, but due to picture quality not good, result is not accurate, So i wants to give that effects to my images. so I read characters from image. how I can achieve this?

Comment: so, basically you are referring to the pre-processing stage to eliminate other alphabets instead of the numbers?

Comment: yes. my question here that how to achieve these effects in openCV, if you have any suggestion regarding OCR, you can provide me

Comment: I didn't down vote. someone else did. Probably you should examine the blobs features. Accept which blobs you want and reject the others. But, it will be tough since all are alpha-numeric. Good luck on that one.

Comment: May be for a start !!!! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python/9620295#9620295

Comment: @AbidRahmanK I wants read characters from image, I already implement code for that, but due to picture quality not good, result is not accurate, So i wants to give that effects to my images. so I read characters from image. please suggest, Am I in right track?

Comment: What you mean by "giving effects"?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK I mean, b/w image with good contrast

Comment: @Gryphon http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_present