# image processing openCV

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OCR using openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248680/ocr-using-opencv)

I wants to convert gray Image into Black and White (with good contrast). I am using openCV. I am struggling from last 3 days but my output image is not clear as show below.

Thanks

Original Image :
[image]

Output Image :

[image]

Comment: @NickBull This is also my question, I think I explain little bit extra in that question, So i Ask again here

Comment: You haven't provided any extra information in this question to your other question. You shouldn't open a new question just because you haven't got an answer on an existing one. Go back to the other question and add more information or respond to questions in the comments to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you to get the proper image

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"EUqAd.jpg"];
        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 150)];
        imageView.image=image;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, image.CGImage);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImage *flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage
                                                scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];

    UIImageView *imageView1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, 150)];
    imageView1.image=flippedImage;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView1];
```