# thresholding in 3 color : black, white, and gray , instead of just black and white

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

**I expect can threshold in 3 color : black, white, and gray , instead of just black and white, that later on I can separate the sticker out from original img**

now my `.py` script can thresholding, make image's color to black and white color

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage.io
import skimage.color
import skimage.filters



# load the image
image = skimage.io.imread("/home/student_joy/desktop/optimization_11_10/original_duplicate.png")[:,:,:3]


# image = imageio.imread(image_name)[:,:,:3]
# img = rgb2gray(image)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(image)


# convert the image to grayscale
gray_image = skimage.color.rgb2gray(image)

# blur the image to denoise
blurred_image = skimage.filters.gaussian(gray_image, sigma=1.0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(blurred_image, cmap="gray")

# create a histogram of the blurred grayscale image
histogram, bin_edges = np.histogram(blurred_image, bins=256, range=(0.0, 1.0))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(bin_edges[0:-1], histogram)
plt.title("Grayscale Histogram")
plt.xlabel("grayscale value")
plt.ylabel("pixels")
plt.xlim(0, 1.0)

# create a mask based on the threshold
t = 0.72
binary_mask = blurred_image < t

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(binary_mask, cmap="gray")


plt.show()
```

see the result pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgOIN.jpg

I'm not sure how to set properly binary_mask , the `t` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
binary_mask = blurred_image < t
```

As you are evaluating a boolean expression on the right, this will give either false (0) or true (1) as target values for your mask (which makes sense if you actually need a mask, it's a binary image).

If you want to separate the sticker regions only (so remove everything grey), you'd do something like

```
t1 = 0.5
t2 = 0.72
binary_mask = 1 - ((t1 < blurred_image) & (blurred_image < t2))
```

or use `cv.threshold()` for a similiar operation.

About finding you threshold: If you follow this link [How to get threshold value from histogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266150/how-to-get-threshold-value-from-histogram) and look up the "Otsu's Binarization " section, it explains how to get a thresholding for a region with a bimodal histogram. Mask out the gray region you just found to only leave the black and white of the stickers, then let Otsu handle the rest.

Comment: [chained comparisons don't work for numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075324/numpy-chained-comparison-with-two-predicates). you have to join both comparison results using `&`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: Ah, missed that. Fixed.